# Python Tkinter Canvas produces broken postscript file

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, postscript

I have a Tkinter canvas with serveral rect-, text- and line-objects on it.

I use the

```
.postscript(file='file.ps')
```

method of the Canvas.

When I try to open the file with ghostscript (on windows and linux) I get the following error:

```
error: undefinedresult in stringwidth
```

Do you have any solutions to this?

Thank you!

EDIT: I'm using python2

Answer (score 4):

The Problem is that the .postscript-Methods only accepts certain fonts. When I changed the font of my Canvas text objects to arial it worked. Although the output font isnt Arial but Courier. I will try to find some fonts which are available by default on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Odd.  Courier should always be available in any PostScript interpreter.

Comment: How do you change it the font? From the editor or through the Python code?

Comment: I encountered a similar issue which yielded the same error message. There seems to be a bug in Tk which generates "0 scalefont" in the postscript by default if you don't explicitly set the size of the font on the canvas.  This will cause division by zero.  Was able to get around it by sizing the font before putting text on the canvas... eg        font create nfont -family Arial -size 18;
c create text 120 120 -text "hello world" -font nfont;